# Possible noise on power line on electric car when the motor works

Tags: motor, filter

I have an IoT device on an electric car. That device has an external 1-wire bus. When the electric motor works I lose connection on the 1-wire bus.

The length of the 1-wire bus is roughly 1m. However it is tested with over 20m cable.

I could not measure the noise on the line because the device is currently in the field and I can only see the results that is no connection on the 1-wire bus although there is a device attached to it.

When the vehicle is stopped and the moror is not working the measurements are correct.

Below the electrical schematic.
50V DC is the line where the motor also supplied. I have a power supply to step down the voltage to 24V and power my device.
In that device there is a 1-wire bus. Voltage of the bus is 3.3V
All grounds are connected in one single spot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOrbpZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will a LC power filter at the 24V power rail do the job?

Comment: Not surprising, a 1-wire interface isn't typically meant to operate over large distances in a high EMI environment.  You could try a filter on the 24 V power rail, but I doubt it will fix the problem.

Comment: @JohnD I use it extensively in automotive environments. Typical cable length around 3-10meters. Never had such a serious issue

Comment: Well, the LIN bus is used in automotive applications and it's a 1-wire interface, but a 1-wire interface on many ICs is intended for communication between devices on a board mostly.  So the details are important, and adding specifics to your question would be helpful.

Comment: All grounds connected at a single point create loops that will couple with the environment through mutual inductance. Prefer a multipoint grounding.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to connect the grounds at only the 24V regulator, use a shielded wire and try and reduce capacitance from the IOT and 1 wire device to the car by using a faraday cage\conductive enclosure.